# Want to rescue GRUB

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, grub

I have ubuntu 12.04 and windows 8 installed on my system. The main boot manager is grub, also the ubuntu and windows are installed in separate partitions. I want to install windows 7 back in place of windows 8, but i want to rescue grub ,so that ubuntu and windows 7 will work fine. Please help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can boot the machine from a Ubuntu LIVE CD and then install/repair grub from that point.
I would recommend looking through the sister site of Superuser.com, ASKUBUNTU.COM